# onTap of Container in flutter want to call a Callback and also setState of the container

Tags: dart, callback, flutter

I am new to dart and flutter. I want to execute a callback onTap of a container as below:

```
final VoidCallback onClick;

onTap: ()  {
  widget.onClick; // this is the callback function
  setState((){
    isClicked = !isClicked;
  });
},
```

However, when I execute the above code the callback is not executed. However, when I write the code as below it is executed:

```
onTap: widget.onClick,
```

How do I achieve to execute the callback ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
widget.onClick()
```

Comment: Yes it is working now @CopsonRoad. Thank you, for your response !